# Netstat not working

Tags: windows, command-prompt

"netstat -a" is not working in command prompt. I received an error:

> netstat is not recognized as an internal or external command

But when I write `netstat - a` with a deliberate error (extra space before "a"), I receive a help info from this command. It's a strange behaviour. 
I tried to run this command from it's folder (`C:\Windows\System32`), but with the same result. 
How can I run this command?

P.S.: My Windows user is an administrator.

Comment: Try `netstat.exe -a`. Also, check `where netstat`.

Answer (score 7):

run `cmd.exe` as an administrator, then try again.

Also, this doesn't belong on stack overflow, [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) is the place for such questions.

Answer (score 2):

Just go to this location "c:\windows\system32" and run. It worked for me. Actually it requires root path.